# Ошибка Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location

Tags: c++, строки, replace

Выдает ошибку Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location
Как я поняла, то ошибка в последней функции replace.
Но что именно не так, не вижу.
В отладчике все значения передает.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>
#include<wchar.h>
#include<algorithm>>
using namespace std;
int main() {

SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int k = 0;
string sentence;
string students[5];
string lowercase[5];
cout << "Введите фамилии студентов:  " << endl;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
{
    getline(cin, students[i]);
}
cout << "Введите предложение с вышуеказанными фамилиями  " << endl;
getline(cin, sentence);
sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);
for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (sentence[i] == '.') {
        sentence[i + 1] = toupper(sentence[i + 1]);
    }
}
cout << sentence << endl;

for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
    lowercase[i] = students[i];
    cout << lowercase[i] << endl;
}
for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
    transform(students[i].begin(), students[i].end(), 
students[i].begin(), tolower);
}
for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
    sentence.replace(sentence.find(students[i]), students[i].length(), 
lowercase[i]);
} cout << sentence << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в **std :: string :: find**. Если в строке нет **students[i]**, то она возвращает **std::string::npos**. Это можно исправить, добавив проверку:

```
if (sentence.find(students[i]) != string::npos)
```

Также, по-моему, у вас перепутаны массивы students, lowercase

[image: Содержимое переменных]

Потому что students[i] не находятся в sentence.
Предлагаю вам разобраться, что хранится в students и исправить последний цикл так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (sentence.find(students[i]) != string::npos) 
            sentence.replace(sentence.find(students[i]), students[i].length(), lowercase[i]);
    }
```